# How to loop through a column in csv using python

Tags: python, loops, csv

I'm currently making a questionnaire on csv and programming using python. I'm trying to make my code loop through the first column in my spreadsheet and to only print the questions which have the key corresponding to what the user has chosen in this case either 1 for earth or 2 for animals...

[image]

The following is the code i have so far but when i loop through this code it doesn't break if the number is not equal to 1. Also i have tried creating a variable which asks the user for the input on which subject they would like to pick. But when i run the program only the last question prints 5 times regardless if the user inputs 1 or 2, only the question at the bottom of the csv file is printed 5 times.

Here is my code!!

```py
with open('questionnaire.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        key = row[0]
        subject = row[1]
        question = row[2]
        option1 = row[3]
        option2 = row[4]
        option3 = row[5]
        option4 = row[6]
        prompt = "Which option do you pick? "
        answer = row[7]
        
        user_prompt = (f"" + question + "\n" + option1 + "\n" + option2 + "\n" +
                       option3 + "\n" + option4 + "\n" + prompt)

        for key in row[0]:
            if key == '1':
                print(key)
            else:
                break

        questionnaire = input(user_prompt)
```

Comment: What is the type of key?

Comment: it shows as a string

Comment: When you say it the loop doesn't break, how do you know? Is it because you start with a number that's not 1 and it still prints something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first for loop is fine, it is iterating over each row. At each iteration you are making `key=row[0]` which is fine. But then you make another for loop that make no sense `for key in row[0]` row[0] is either 1 or 2 there is no goal in making a for loop here. I think what you want is start with an input to the user enter the option 1 or 2 (before the for loop) and then, inside the for loop, if key is equal to the user choice you print user_prompt. Is it clear?

[edited] Try this and then create another if/else statement to verify if the user answer is equal to the right answer

```
selection = input("1 for earth 2 for animals")

with open('questionnaire.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        key = row[0]
        subject = row[1]
        question = row[2]
        option1 = row[3]
        option2 = row[4]
        option3 = row[5]
        option4 = row[6]
        prompt = "Which option do you pick? "
        answer = row[7]
        
        user_prompt = (f"" + question + "\n" + option1 + "\n" + option2 + "\n" +
                       option3 + "\n" + option4 + "\n" + prompt)

        if key == selection:
            user_answer = input(user_prompt)
```

Comment: I think i have tried what you are suggesting here is what i had previously. It outputs the question 5 times which is what i want but it doesn't run through each question and instead only prints the final question in my dataset 5 times. 
with open('questionnaire.csv', 'r') as questionFile:
    questionFileReader = csv.reader(questionFile)
    hello = input("Which subject would you like to pick? ")
    for key in questionFileReader:
        if key[0] == hello:

Comment: maybe because you were changing key. I edited the solution with a code. See if it does what you need.